# How do I let other people into my world in the newest version of Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to let my brother into my world, but it's not working. We even changed the settings on both devices. I am using a kindle fire, he's using an iPad. How can we play with each other?

Comment: Wifi is activated on both devices? They are both on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you are both on the same Wi-Fi network. Then enter your world and see if your brother can join. If not, go under Options and see if the "Server Visible" or something similarly named is checked off. If so, turn it on. Finally, make sure you both have the same version, and that both of you have the full version, or else it wont let you play multiplayer.